# If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded an open then every sequence of $A$ has a subsequence that converges to a point of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded an open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that every sequence of $A$ has a subsequence that converges to a point of $A$?

If $\{x_k\}$ is a sequence of points in $A$ then it is bounded because $A$ is bounded. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theoren, if $\{x_k\}$ is bounded then it has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{k_r}\}$. However, does $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}x_{k_r}$ have to be in $A$?

Comment: $A=(0,1),$ $x_n=1/n.$ $\dots$

Comment: This is telepathy. +1

Comment: Yes. Just the same example.

Comment: In $\Bbb R^n$ this is true for $closed$ bounded sets only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is false even for $n=1$.

Let $A$ be the open unit interval $]0,1[$, and let the series be $1/n$.